# Is there a way to install Rational Rhapsody on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, rhapsody

Is it possible to install Rational Rhapsody on Mac OSX (directly, not through Parallels)? Any key tweaks to making work?

I am specifically using OSX 10.7.4 and looking at Rhapsody 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe not possible. Rhapsody is built mostly on MS .net object; and installed with MS typical installer. If you figure it out, I am interested to know it.

Comment: It's been a few years since I took the class, but my recollection was that we ran the IDE on linux boxes (I think -- and this is really a stretch -- it was integrated with Eclipse with some fancy "round-tripping" or something).  See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_7.5.3/com.ibm.rhapsody.installing.doc/topics/rhp_t_iu_installing_rhp_linux.html?cp=SSB2MU_7.5.3&lang=en